# MVC3 form posting with value and file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC3 and I would like to create a form with input column and file upload.

The problem comes when I try to do both thing at the same time.

Here is my code

```
...
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult About(string inputStr)
    {
        string local = inputStr;
        string[] word = inputStr.Split(':');
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetFile(string inputStr, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string filename = file.FileName;
        return RedirectToAction("About");
    }
```

These two are my controllers

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetFile", "Home", (new { inputStr = "111" }), FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){
<div class="editor">

  <input type="file" name="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="OK" id="submitFile" class="testingSubmit"/>

</div>
}
```

This code works well for uploading files, and sending string "111" to the controller.

Here is another jQuery function

```
$('.testingSubmit').click(function () {
          var totalString="";
        $('.editor-field :input').each(function () {
            alert($(this).val());
            totalString += $(this).val().toString() + ":";
        });

        $('form').submit();
       /* $.post("About", { inputStr: totalString}, function (data) {

        });*/
    });
```

Here, what I am trying to do is the get the user input and put it on string totalString.
I was able to post the totalString to the controller by using $.post

My questions are:
1. Am i on the right track? i.e. Is that possible to do those two tasks together with one post?
2. If not, what are the possible solution for this?

Thank you very much for your attention and hopefully this can be solved!

Comment: You might consider posting this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for your advice Eric but may I know the differences?

Comment: Both sites overlap, however this one tends to have questions like "Why doesn't my code work?", while codereview has questions like "Is my code the best way to do this?  What can I do to make it better?"  Its not a very big difference, but if you don't get an answer here, try over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("GetFile", "Home", (new { inputStr = "111" }), FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmGetFile", enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){
    <div class="editor">

      <input type="file" name="file" />
      <input type="hidden" name="totalString" id="totalString"/>
      <input type="submit" value="OK" id="submitFile" onclick="submitGetFileForm()" class="testingSubmit"/>

    </div>
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
function submitGetFileForm(e)
{
   e.preventDefault();
   var total = //build your total string here
   $('#totalString').val(total);
   $('#frmGetFile').submit();
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetFile(string totalString, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        // your action logic..
    }
```